# What is a greedy algorithm that choses n pairs such that the max ∆ in the pairs is as small as possible?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I have *n* puppies with a size and *n* kittens with a size and I want to make puppy-kitten pairs. In particular, I would like a puppy-kitten pair with as small of a size difference as possible.

What would be an efficient, greedy algorithm that chooses *n* puppy-kitten pairs so that the size difference between the
most size-disparate pair is as small as possible?  More precisely, denote by s_i the size of puppy i and s_j denote the size of kitten j. Given a pair <i, j>, let ∆(i, j) = | s_i − s_j |. The algorithm should choose pairings to ensure the largest ∆(i, j) over all of your pairings is as small as possible.

Here’s an example: there are three puppies of sizes 6, 4, and 9 and three kittens of sizes 8, 7, and 3. If you pair them <6, 8>, <4, 7> , <9, 3> then the maximum ∆ is 6, whereas if you pair them <6, 7> , <4, 3> , <9, 8>, the maximum ∆ is 1, which is clearly optimal (because, for example, the puppy with size 6 can only
be matched to a kitten whose size is ≥ 1 away from the puppy’s size).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a homework dump without any attempt of a solution.

Comment: @Henry It is not a homework question, and I do have a solution but I am a bit busy at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **optimal greedy algorithm** is:

1. **Sort puppies** from smallest to largest (ties are broken arbitrarily). Denote such list `P`.
2. **Sort kittens** from smallest to largest (ties are broken arbitrarily). Denote such list `K`.
3. **Select pairs** according to their indexes `(P[0], K[0])`, `(P[1], K[1])`, ..., `(P[n - 1], K[n - 1])`.

Such choice can be **proved optimal** using **Exchange Argument**.

**Definition**: A list has an **inversion** if there are **two pairs** `(a, d)` and `(b, c)` such that `a < b` and `c < d`.

**Lemma 1**: All arrangements with no inversions have the same ∆. (a task for you :P, compare what happen in case of `a = b` and `c < d`, `a < b` and `c = d`)

**Claim**: There is an optimal arrangement that has no inversions.
Proof. There exist at least an optimal arrangement, let's call it `O`.
If `O` has no inversions we are done.
Else after swapping `(a, d)` and `(b, c)` for `(a, c)` and `(b, d)` we get an optimal arrangement with one less inversion. The initial arrangement can have at most C<sup>n</sup><sub>2</sub> inversions, and hence after at most C<sup>n</sup><sub>2</sub> swaps we get an optimal arrangement with no inversions.

We know that `a < b` and `c < d`. Forcing the other inequalities:

1. `a <= c` and `b <= d`:
   `|a - d| = max(|a - d|, |b - c|) >= max(|a - c|, |b - d|)`
2. `c <= a` and `b <= d`:
   `|a - d| >= |b - d|` and `|b - c| >= |a - c|` then `max(|a - d|, |b - c|) >= max(|a - c|, |b - d|)`
3. `a <= c` and `d <= b`:
   `|a - d| >= |a - c|` and `|b - c| >= |b - d|` then `max(|a - d|, |b - c|) >= max(|a - c|, |b - d|)`
4. `a >= c` and `d <= b`:
   `|b - c| = max(|a - d|, |b - c|) >= max(|a - c|, |b - d|)`

In all cases swapped arrangement does not increase ∆ value and we know that initial arrangement has optimal ∆ value so our claim is true.

By **lemma 1** and **claim** the greedy algorithm is optimal.

Comment: "All arrangements with no inversions have the same ∆" do you mean if I were to rearrange the pairings of cats and dogs, the difference of each pair would still be the same? Or if I were to switch who they were matched with?

Comment: @JohnAdams Look at the definition of inversion to understand your questions and their answers. It's all there. If two different matchings have no inversions then they have the same ∆.